# WCF service within a Web application hosted on HTTPS

Tags: asp.net, wcf, https

I have an existing ASP.NET web application running in Production (.NET 4.0, IIS 7.0) on HTTPS (let's call it https://myapp.com). Now there is a requirement to add a new WCF Service to the application which will be consumed by a desktop application located on a different server. Here is what I have done:

1. Add a new WCF Service (called myService.svc) in a directory /WebServices in my existing project (works fine on localhost).
2. Publish website as usual.
3. Configure my web service in `web.config` as follows:

Config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="TransportSecurity">
        <security mode="Transport">
          <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
        </security>
      </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>

  <services>
    <service name="myService" behaviorConfiguration="myBehavior">
      <endpoint address="https://myapp.com/Webservices/myService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
         bindingConfiguration="TransportSecurity" contract="myService"/>
      <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
    </service>
  </services>

  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="myBehavior">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

In my mind, I have done all that is required. When I run the URL `https://myapp.com/WebServices/myService.svc` in a browser, I get 'resource not found'. To double check, I create a test console application and try to 'Add Service Reference' using the same URL but it fails to discover it.

What am I doing wrong? I am a novice to WCF and have been stuck in this issue for too long.

Comment: can you show your web.config, 'as follows' ?

Comment: Did you also added https binding in iid

Comment: Sorry was having trouble putting code there. Thanks @marc_s. As you can tel, never asked any questions here before.

Comment: @evgenyl, the website has been running for a few years on HTTPS, so I'm guessing HTTPS bindings are there in IIS already. Unless there is something specific that needs to be done for the service?

Comment: If you put plsin html file in this folder - can you see it?

Comment: Yes plain html and aspx forms in this folder are accessible just fine.

Comment: The issue has been resolved. I did two things: I removed 'httpGetEnabled=true' because there was no endpoint defined on plain http (non-https). Secondly, I set `aspNetCompatibilityEnabled` to false.